# React setInterval function keeps running in the background after rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-state

I am using `setInterval` inside `useEffect` with an empty dependency array inside one of my react components.
There is true/false `useState` which controls the display of that component.
When the state is false, the component is hidden and when it's true the component is shown.

Something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false)

// in jsx render section

return (
   <div>
      {state? <component/> : '' }
   </div>
)
```

When the component loads for the first time the `setInterval` runs only one time which is what it supposes to do.

If the state goes to false then back to true, the component is removed from the UI and is then displayed back again. However, what happens here is now I have two `setInterval` functions running in the background, and the first one doesn't shutdown.

The number of the `setInterval` functions keeps increasing with each time that component re-render.

I don't understand how React works in this situation.

I need to know how it works (i.e. why won't the function shutdown, why are the number of functions increasing) and how to fix it.

Comment: Intervals run constantly until you explicitly stop them via `clearInterval`. Not a React thing, that's just how they work in JS. You say you only want it to run once, maybe you're wanting to use a `setTimeout`. Hard to tell without any code for the interval stuff

Comment: You'll need to share your component code. What it sounds like is you're missing the `useEffect` _cleanup function_, which can be used to clear the interval when the component unmounts.

Comment: Yea cleanup function was missing, everything worked fine when I added it.
Thanks for your comment, and sorry for not writing the whole code I just thought this was enough to explain my question.

Answer (score 4):

This is the structure of React useEffect.React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //effect
    return () => {
        //cleanup runs on unmount
    }
}, [])
```

The cleanup function should have clearInterval() which will basically removes setInterval or stops it when component unmounts. See the practical code below:

```
let intervalid;
useEffect(
    () => {
     intervalid = setInterval(() => {console.log("Iterate");}, 1000));

      return function cleanup() {
        console.log("cleaning up");
        clearInterval(intervalid);
      };
    },
    []
  );
```

This above code is just for understanding approach. Every effect may return a function that cleans up after it. This lets us keep the logic for adding and removing subscriptions close to each other. # FROM REACT DOCS [Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

Answer (score 0):

I have used answer number one of Sidharth, but it did not work always, this is actually an issue in React Native and react native has already added another hook to deal with this.

If you are here from react native then you can remove the screen from the navigation stack which is not an optimal answer but will do the job for now.

you can do something like this

```
navigation.replace("NextScreen)
```

this will remove the current screen completely from the stack and obviously, if the screen is removed everything in the screen will get removed hence the setInterval as well.